# MYSQL: Join with many to many

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, view

I'm trying to create a view and trying to see what can be done, I have a main table a table I want to join to and also a junction table.

```
Event table (it's very big so it's just dummy data):

+----+----------+----------+
| id | somethin | somethin |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | value    | value    |
+----+----------+----------+

Junction Table:

+----+----------+----------+
| id | event_id | label_id |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |        1 |        1 |
+----+----------+----------+

Labels Table:

+----+--------+-----------+
| id | name   | value     |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Name1  | Value1    |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish I'm not sure if is possible, the labels would have a lot of different name and a set amount of values so imagine

```
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | name   | value     |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Name1  | Value1    |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Name1  | Value2    |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Name2  | Value3    |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | Name2  | Value4    |
+----+--------+-----------+
```

So this is the tricky part I would like to have on the join table the to have all the data from the event table, plus on top of that a column names after the name of the label and the value corresponding to that event. something like this

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| id | Name     | Place    | Name1    | Name2    |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | value    | value    | Value2   | Null     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

so the name column will be there regardless of whether or now that record has a label against it but it will show null if nothing is there.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a view that dynamically adjusts the number of columns returned. That's something you need to implement with client-logic. At least with all databases I know of (you don't mention which database system you use).

Comment: I'm using MySQL, would that be the case even if I knew the amount of names the label has? just unknown number of values, I was thinking maybe I could join multiple times with a WHERE clause for each different name

Comment: I haven't fully understood the question in all details, as the example is not consistent, but if the number of columns remains constant you can create a view. It just isn't possible to change the number of columns based on data in a table (neither by Events nor Labels table). If it remains constant, you can just join multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You could join the label table multiple times under different aliases specifying in the where clause that entries for the 2nd join be not equal to the 1st. Entries for the 3rd be not equal to the 1st or 2nd etc.

e.g.

Say we have a table of people

```
id name
1 Paul
2 James
3 Scott
```

and a table of places they have visited

```
id peopleid placename
1 1 Africa
2 1 Australia
3 2 Africa
```

Then we could have a query like

```
select n.name, p1.placename, p2.placename
from name as n
left outer join place as p1 on p1.peopleid = n.id
left outer join place as p2 on p2.peopleid = n.id
where p2.id != p1.id
```

for these results:

```
Paul Africa Australia
James Africa NULl
Scott NULL NULL
```